# Pinescript CC values incorrect and changing even though the timeframe cannot be changed

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a fixed 1H to 24H intraday CC table or plot.

Even though I have a fixed timeframe, the values are still changing and incorrect:

1H timeframe target chart: Only the 1H CC seems to be correct if I compare it with the CC indicator by TV. The others are incorrect.

All the other timeframe target charts are incorrect.

Here is the script:

```
//@version=5


// Rules
indicator(title="I: Correlation Coefficient Table", shorttitle="I: CC T", precision=2, scale=scale.right)


// Inputs
sym_s = input.symbol(defval="BINANCE:BTCUSD", title="Symbol Source")
src = input.source(defval=close, title="Source")
len = input.int(defval=14, title="Length", minval=1, step=1)
sym_t = input.symbol(defval="BINANCE:ETHUSD", title="Symbol Target")


// Core
src_s_1h = request.security(symbol=sym_s, timeframe="60", expression=src)
src_s_2h = request.security(symbol=sym_s, timeframe="120", expression=src)
src_s_3h = request.security(symbol=sym_s, timeframe="180", expression=src)

src_t_1h = request.security(symbol=sym_t, timeframe="60", expression=src)
src_t_2h = request.security(symbol=sym_t, timeframe="120", expression=src)
src_t_3h = request.security(symbol=sym_t, timeframe="180", expression=src)

cc_1h = ta.correlation(source1=src_s_1h, source2=src_t_1h, length=len)
cc_2h = ta.correlation(source1=src_s_2h, source2=src_t_2h, length=len)
cc_3h = ta.correlation(source1=src_s_2h, source2=src_t_3h, length=len)

cc_r_1h = math.round(number=cc_1h, precision=3)
cc_r_2h = math.round(number=cc_2h, precision=3)
cc_r_3h = math.round(number=cc_3h, precision=3)


// Table
cc_table = table.new(position=position.bottom_center, columns=5, rows=3, bgcolor=color.black, frame_color=color.white, frame_width=2, border_color=color.white, border_width=1)

table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=1, row=1, text="TF", bgcolor=color.white)
table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=1, row=2, text="CC", bgcolor=color.white)

table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=2, row=1, text="1H", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=color.black)
table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=3, row=1, text="2H", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=color.black)
table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=4, row=1, text="3H", text_color=color.white, bgcolor=color.black)

table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=2, row=2, text=str.tostring(value=cc_r_1h), text_color=color.white, bgcolor=color.black)
table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=3, row=2, text=str.tostring(value=cc_r_2h), text_color=color.white, bgcolor=color.black)
table.cell(table_id=cc_table, column=4, row=2, text=str.tostring(value=cc_r_3h), text_color=color.white, bgcolor=color.black)
```

Is it possible to somehow do an input*symbol() where I do something like BINANCE:BTCUSD:1H (or 60)? I tried this and it didn't work, and I can't find a format page on how to do this.

Could the ta.correlation() function be cursed?